# Open pop on click of custom action and get filled data

Tags: plugin-development, craft2

I created a new custom action.

A new button is added in `getAvailableActions()` as we can se in below screenshot in red marked rectangle, now when i click on that button 
 (`Cusotm Action`) i want to open a pop up box ( i used [Default pop up](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/garnishjs/blob/master/src/Modal.js) js lib.

[image: custombutton]

Template File path : /craft/plugins/tagmanager/templates/_mergetags.twig

```
{% includeJsResource "tagmanager/js/tagmanager.js" %}

    <div class="btn menubtn btnMeregeTags" role="button">{{ "Merge Tags"|t }}</div>
    <div class="menu">
    <div id="mergetags-modal" class="modal"> 
        <div id="modal" class="body">
            <header class="header">
                <h2>Modal header</h2>
            </header>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

js part

```
$(function () {
  $modal = new Garnish.Modal($('#mergetags-modal')); //create a new modal
  $modal.show();
});
```

[image: default pop up]

Not able to open pop up correctly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your Question is exactly and what your expected outcome is but to create a Modal you can use this HTML

```html
<div id="my-awesome-modal" class="modal">
    <div id="modal-body" class="body">
        <header class="header">
            <h2>My Awesome Modal</h2>
        </header>
    </div>
</div>
```

and via JavaScript you can show it

```JS
//create it
var modal = new Garnish.Modal($('#my-awesome-modal')); 
modal.show();
```

Comment: I am not able to add any js event on my custom button which is created by adding a new action

Comment: Why are you not able to do that?